# when back to activity app crashed

Tags: android

my code work properly and play music background of main activity but in the my code when go to another activity by buttons when back to main activity by back press,app crash and force closed.

what can i do?

please help me

this is my activity:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
AnimationDrawable anim;
MediaPlayer player;
BackgroundSound mBackgroundSound = new BackgroundSound();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);
    anim = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
    ImageButton btnfehrest=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnfehrest);
    btnfehrest.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton btndarbareh=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btndarbareh);
    btndarbareh.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnfehrest :
        Intent infehrest=new Intent(Main.this,Fehrest.class);
        startActivity(infehrest);
        break;
    case R.id.btndarbareh :
        Intent indarbareh=new Intent(Main.this,DarbarehMain.class);
        startActivity(indarbareh);
        break;
    }
}
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        anim.start();
    } else {
        anim.stop();
    }
}
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mBackgroundSound.execute(null);
}
public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.chera); 
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping 
        player.setVolume(100,100); 
        player.start(); 
        return null;
    }
}
 }
```

and my logcat:

```
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.aseman14.fatemiye/com.aseman14.fatemiye.Main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:957)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:383)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.aseman14.fatemiye.Main.onResume(Main.java:68)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
04-02 12:04:04.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: where are log errors ?

Comment: Please post your logcat here

Comment: We need your stack trace.

Comment: probably mBackgroundSound is null when you return to the `Activity`

Comment: i guess the already started asyntask i.e BackgroundSound is tried to start again because it is define in onResume. therefore its crashed.

Comment: You will try this one you will not get any problem with asynchtask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse a task. You have to create a new every time.

Replace

```
mBackgroundSound.execute(null);
```

With:

```
mBackgroundSound = new BackgroundSound();
mBackgroundSound.execute(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the already started asyntask i.e `BackgroundSound` is tried to start again because it is define in `onResume`. therefore its get crashed. define it in `onCreate` then try. i guess it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove the following line from `onResume` and check it.

```
mBackgroundSound.execute(null);
```

Its because you are try to run a task which is already in running. So before start executing in `onResume` check whether the task is running state or not. Or try to stop it before staet execute again and then execute the task. I don't whether this is correct way or not. Anyway let me know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you definig te Asynch task instance in the class using that asynch task instanse you can perform only one time in the activity so you will try to create the instance where you are requiring in the class i will suggest this answer it will works definitely....

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    BackgroundSound mBackgroundSound = new BackgroundSound();
    mBackgroundSound.execute(null);
}
```